# what is the best way to connect my application with kernel?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel

I know this question can be answered by searching in google. But I have spent nights in searching to try make my application connect with my programmed driver.
When I start searching I read some Techniques to how to share information between user-mode and kernel-mode and these Techniques are:

•   I/O requests

•   Synchronization and notification

•   Shared handles

•   Shared memory

this [white paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110401190309/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487414) explain these Techniques. But I am confused!!! which technique is the best????
For I/O requests: well..., I don't understand it perfeclty but what I know (briefly) about it that exchange data whenever an application requests an I/O operation, and this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explain I/O control codes.

I have read many complex articles, but I don't know the road that lead me to the right way to make my program works fast without delay in exchanging data with the driver.

So, I asked : **what is the best way to connect my application with kernel??**
And I mean **"the best way"**.
This is my driver code:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

VOID
Unload(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
)
{
    DbgPrint("Driver Unloaded");
};


NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPathName
)
{
    DbgPrint("Driver Loaded");
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
};
```

As you see, the driver is simple. Do nothing except output "Driver loaded" when it load and "Driver unloaded" when it unload.
Only I want is make this driver able to receive from the user and print it, make the program receive from the driver and print it.
I don't want made code, I just want from you to guide me : what I must to do? and what is the best way to do it?

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a Symbolic link in DriverEntry using `IoCreateSymbolicLink`

Then from the user mode program call `CreateFile` with the name of the symbolic link and use either `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` or `DeviceIoControl` to send/receive data to/from the driver.

For `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` option you need to implement `IRP_MJ_READ`/`IRP_MJ_WRITE` processing in your driver.

For `DeviceIoControl` you need to handle `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL`.

Here's a very nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-1-Introduction-to-Drivers) demonstrating this technique, with sample code for both kernel and user mode. I copied main parts from it related to your question:

```
//how to create symbolic link

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT  pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING  pRegistryPath)
{
    UNICODE_STRING usDriverName, usDosDeviceName;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&usDriverName, L"\\Device\\Example");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&usDosDeviceName, L"\\DosDevices\\Example"); 

    IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, 0, &usDriverName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &pDeviceObject);


    IoCreateSymbolicLink(&usDosDeviceName, &usDriverName);
}

//How to use from user mode
int main()
{

    hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\Example", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

   //use ReadFile, WriteFile, or DeviceioControl here

    return 0;
}
```